# Display Number with SI prefixes

Tags: formatting

I have a number of `val = 0.000015783` which represents a current value in Amps.

I want to display it with 3 significant digits and with SI prefixes instead of the usual power notation. So the target result is: `15.8µ`

The closest I can get to is:

```
EngineeringForm[val, 3]
```

which yields: `15.8x10^-6`. However I can't find a way to replace to `x10^-6` with a `µ`.

I also couldn't find any way to do it using the `Quantity` function.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UnitConvert`, `Quantity`, and `SetPrecision` can convert a numerical value of amperes to µA with 3 significant digits.

```
val = 0.000015783;
UnitConvert[Quantity[SetPrecision[val, 3],"Amperes"],"MicroAmperes"]
(* 15.8 µA *)
```

Change the amperes quantity to a string with `StringReplace` and `TextString`.

```
StringReplace["A"|" "->""]@TextString@
  UnitConvert[Quantity[SetPrecision[val,3],"Amperes"],"MicroAmperes"]
(* 15.8µ *)
```

We can use these methods for a function that converts a numerical ampere value to a quantity value with an SI prefix and designated number of significant digits. The function selects the SI prefix that corresponds to engineering notation. Values outside of the known prefixes are converted to amperes and adjusted for precision, but without a prefix.

```
sciPrefix[n_, sd_?IntegerQ] := Module[{
  prefix = Switch[Quotient[Log10[n], 3], 0,"",-1,"Milli",-2,"Micro",-3,"Nano"],
  v = SetPrecision[Quantity[n, "Amperes"], sd]},
  If[Head[prefix] === String,
    UnitConvert[v, prefix<>"Amperes"],
    v]]
```

Then:

```
sciPrefix[val, 3]
(* 15.8 µA *)

Table[sciPrefix[val*Power[10,e], 3], {e,-5,8}](* etc. *)
```

Add the string conversion steps to convert a numeric ampere value to a formatted string.

```
sciPrefixText[n_, sd_?IntegerQ] := Module[{
  prefix = Switch[Quotient[Log10[n], 3], 0,"",-1,"Milli",-2,"Micro",-3,"Nano"],
  v = SetPrecision[Quantity[n, "Amperes"], sd]},
  StringReplace["A"|" "->""]@TextString@If[Head[prefix]===String,
    UnitConvert[v, prefix<>"Amperes"],
    v]]

sciPrefixText[val, 3]
(* 15.8µ *)
sciPrefixText[val, 4]
(* 15.78µ *)
```

It’s easy to add SI prefixes by changing `Switch`. For example,

```
Switch[Quotient[Log10[n], 3], 1,”Kilo”,0,””,-1,”Milli”,-2,”Micro”,-3,”Nano”,-4,”Pico”]
```

Where the numbers are the integer powers of 1000 and the matching prefixes from [mathworld.wolfram.com/SIPrefixes.html](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SIPrefixes.html).

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer. I don't use all parts of it but it is a solid starting point for many associated problems.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you can use the following to produce a Quantity object:

```
val=0.000015783;
UnitConvert[val, "Micro"]
```

> 15.783

Comment: thanks. This is the type of integration I was looking for. Looks like `Quantity` does understand the concept of SI prefixes.

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
si[val0_] := Module[{val = val0, count = 0},
  If[Abs@val > 1,
   While[Abs@val >= 10^3, count++; val /= 10^3];
   pre = Switch[count, 1, "k", 2, "mega", 3, "giga", 4, "tera", _, ""]
   ,
   While[Abs@val < 1, count++; val *= 10^3];
   pre = Switch[count, 1, "mili", 2, "\[Mu]", 3, "nano", 4, "pico", _,
      ""]
   ];
  StringForm["`` ``", NumberForm[val, 3], pre]
  ]

si[15.8 10^-6]
 15.8 μ
```

Note, the output is only for display, you can not use it for further calculations.

Comment: Thanks. It works but my feeling is that there is a more elegant way. And with the clumsy Wolfram syntax, we are all looking for more elegance, arent we ? :) Reason is, that this page exists, which lets me hope for a hidden direct integration in Mathematica: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SIPrefixes.html I'll mark you as Answer, if that should turn out to be not the case

Answer (score 3):

I think `EngineeringForm` will do the job if it is given the right formatting function.

Consider

```
munger[m_, b_, e_] :=
  Switch[e,
    "-3", m <> "m",
    "-6", m <> "μ",
    "-9", m <> "n",
    "", m,
    _, Row[{m, "×", Superscript[b, e]}]]
EngineeringForm[1.57831×10^Range[4, -10, -1], 3, NumberFormat -> munger]
```

> ```
> {15.8×10^3, 1.58×10^3, 158., 15.8, 1.58, 158.m, 15.8m, 1.58m, 
>  158.μ, 15.8μ, 1.58μ, 158.n, 15.8n, 1.58n, 158.×10^-12}
> ```

Will that work for you?

Comment: thanks for pointing me to `NumberFormat`, which looks very powerful. It is very elegant. I took the `m<>` in front of `Switch` to make it even nicer. Still, I like the integration with `Quantity` even more as it feels more native. So I will set creidhes post as the answer.

Comment: (Sorry can't edit anymore) Also, when passing a `Quantity` object to `EngineeringForm`, there'll be an ugly space between e.g. `µ` and `A`, which is avoided when using the prefix also within `Quantity`

Comment: @tobalt. It is just my opinion, but I don't like the idea of trying to integrate `Quantity` with this approach. Everything passed into a formatting function is a string and its output is expected to be a string. `Quantity` objects are not strings.

Comment: (the @ statement keeps getting deleted...) Indeed. This and Quantity don't harmonize well. Even though I marked another post as answer, I am still using this (for an automatic Legend display). I just place the unit string "A" into the format string to make it work.

Comment: @tobalt.   @ callouts get deleted if the person named has not made a comment to the post where you are commenting.